# Updating Value In Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, shopping-cart

I have a database table called Product. Inside, there's ID, ProductName, Brand, Description, Price, Cost and Count. I would like to update the Count value using a textbox.

For example, if I type in a value in the textbox, and there is already 10 under the Count, the updated value should be the value in the textbox + 10.

Here are my codes:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string productName = ddlName.Text;
        string quantity = tbQuantity.Text;

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrimberlandConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        string strCommandText = "Select ProductName FROM Product WHERE ProductName = @ProductName";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", productName);
        myConnect.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        addStocks(productName, quantity);

        reader.Close();
        myConnect.Close();
    }

    private void addStocks(string productName, string quantity)
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrimberlandConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        string strCommandText = "UPDATE Product SET Count = Count + 1 ";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", productName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count", quantity);

        myConnect.Open();

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (result > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Stocks have successfully been added.");
        }

        myConnect.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Does it work?  If not, what's the problem?  Do you get any error codes?  On any specific lines?

Comment: @Ian it works but it only adds 1. I need it to add the value that I key in the textbox. But I'm not sure how to modify the query.

Comment: @GrantWinney the strCommandText in addStocks. It works, but I need it to add the value that I've keyed in the textbox and not just +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string productName = ddlName.Text;
    string quantity = tbQuantity.Text;
    string product_id = "";

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrimberlandConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    string strCommandText = "Select ID FROM Product WHERE lower(ProductName) = lower(@ProductName)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", productName);
    myConnect.Open();
    product_id = cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null ? "" : cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    myConnect.Close();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(product_id))
        addStocks(product_id, quantity);
}

private void addStocks(string productID, string quantity)
{
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrimberlandConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    string strCommandText = "UPDATE Product SET Count = Count + @val where ID = @PID ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", productID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", quantity);
    try{
        myConnect.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Stocks have successfully been added.");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //work with exception
    }
    finally{
        myConnect.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just dump a large listing of code on us and let us figure out what you've changed - please **EXPLAIN** what you changed - and why.

Comment: First of all, I'm taking ProductID from database. If it does exists, I'm updating the Count value by inputted value, otherwise don't do anything. Also I'm updating value of required Product, not of all, as it is on the question

Comment: @marc_s Sorry for such phrases, but if you need, I may comment each line on the code, where I make edit.

Comment: That's fine - just tell us something like : *I've added a WHERE clause to the UPDATE statement to update a specific product - not all* - that would be more than sufficient. Without it, we're left to compare your code to the original code and figure out ourselves what it is you've changed (and maybe sometimes it wouldn't be this obvious). Your response is right on the spot and solves the problem - just **tell us** what you've done and what the reasoning behind it is - then the response is truly perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to modify the command text:

```
    string strCommandText = "UPDATE Product SET Count = Count + 1 ";
```

to

```
    string strCommandText = "UPDATE Product SET Count = Count + @count WHERE ProductName = @ProductName  ";
```

That should be all from a purely functional perspective.

But to make it a bit more bullet proof, you should to a check on the 'quantity' string to make sure that it is indeed a number.